# Why does this double integral give me different answers?

Tags: calculus, integration

According to the following link:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Change-of-Variables-of-Double-Integrals/?ALLSTEPS

The double integral ultimately evaluates to 1.58362 after variable replacement.

However, when I try the original version in Wolfram:

evaluate Integrate[sin(x+y)*cos(x-y),  {x,0,2},{y,-x,x}]

I get .464443 -- what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link has a mistake at $9$th step while evaluating the inner integral. It should be :

$$\begin{align} \\ \dfrac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^4\int\limits_0^{4-u} \sin(u)\cos(v)~dv du &=  \dfrac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^4\sin(u)\sin(v)~\Bigg|_0^{4-u}  du \\~\\ &=\dfrac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^4\sin(u)\color{red}{\sin(4-u)} du\\~\\&=\cdots \end{align} $$